# What are some alternatives to ASI iMIS Content Management Systems?

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

I am working with a team to select a new content management system for a large membership organization (around 25,000 members). The organization has revenue so I'm not looking for a dirt cheap solution.

The site currently uses ASI iMIS which is based on ColdFusion. It's difficult to work with and not flexible for our needs.

What other possible alternatives to ASI iMIS are there?

Ideally the solution would have some sort of support from the vendor.

So far I've come up with:

- Drupal/Acquia
- SDL Tridion
- Plone
- Ellington (probably too news like)
- Pinax (probably not developed enough)

Comment: The sentence starting with "The organization has revenue" seems to have a word missing in it somewhere. Are you, or are you not, looking for dirt cheap? Also: requirements? What's inflexible about your current system? There's nothing to work with here. You're just going to get an arbitrary list of applications liked by whoever's responding at the moment.

Comment: Yes I did have a typo. What is inflexible about the current setup is that it's a legacy cold fusion app. If we want to display youtube videos we can't; if we want to create new content types we can't, if we want to display calendar events we can't. But basically, the requirement is for a large organization what is a responsible choice, given the consequences of a website failure.

Comment: I know your post is over a year old, but your comments... "Yes I did have a typo. What is inflexible about the current setup is that it's a legacy cold fusion app. If we want to display youtube videos we can't; if we want to create new content types we can't, if we want to display calendar events we can't. But basically, the requirement is for a large organization what is a responsible choice, given the consequences of a website failure." Are really not reasonable. I've used the Coldfusion iMIS e-series since June, 1999 and found that it was really easy to do just what you are saying you can't

Answer (score 2):

If you have Java skills, take a look at OpenCms - http://www.opencms.org/ - It's a very flexible solution, and has some very advanced features.  I've used it for a number of sites, and have also used some of the additional modules such as the forms and newsletter modules from http://www.alkacon.com/en/products/oamp/index.html.  If you can get over the initial learning curve, you'll find OpenCms to be both powerful and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully integrated the open source Umbraco cms at a number of sites.  All integration components are available.